# Trick to open complete bracket at once

Tags: matlab

**Problem**

I assume everyone knows the problem, to forget to close a bracket or simply that it is just annoying to always type an open bracket `( [ {` and then close it manually again `)]}`.

**Hence this maybe off-the wall question:**

Is there a trick to open the open and closing part of a bracket at once, so that you could simply write in the middle ? 
I know this works in notepad++, but I prefer writing in the matlab editor just not to have to switch between windows, to test parts of my code.

I guess there is an easy solution, but I couldnt find anything online and I assume this might be interesting question not just for me!

**Edit**

After posting a service request, it becomes clear there is no possibility for this up to matlab R2016a. It might be considered in future matlab releases, so we can hope for the best.

Comment: Not an easy solution, but I usually type opening and closing brackets at once, before writing anything in between. For instance, my typing procedure looks like `disp()` ⇨  `disp([])` ⇨ `disp([num2str()])` ⇨ `disp([num2str(magic())])` ⇨ `disp([num2str(magic(4))])`.

Comment: You can also change your default Maltab editor to any other in preferences tab http://i.imgur.com/R30oafW.png

Comment: And also request a feature as described here: http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2008/01/14/making-a-feature-request/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was already hidden in the question, I will post it here so the quesition does not remain open:

> After posting a service request, it becomes clear there is no
>   possibility for this up to matlab R2016a. It might be considered in
>   future matlab releases, so we can hope for the best.

In addition to this, the obvious workarounds are:

- Use a different editor
- Type the brackets as you think about them logically. This was suggested in the comments and I also do this when I write complicated formulas.

The excellent example by @brainkz

`disp()` ⇨ `disp([])` ⇨ `disp([num2str()])` ⇨ `disp([num2str(magic())])` ⇨ `disp([num2str(magic(4))])`

Answer (score -1):

Just open phanthesis when you need and close them at the end. Matlab editor helps you by underscoring the bracket you are closing.